# Can I load 2 xml doc in an .ajax() call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know whether I can parse the 2 different xml documents in the jquery.ajax() call.
I am able to parse the 1 single xml file, but now I want to expand it to 2 xml doc. is that possible?
Here is what I am doing for 1 xml file

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sample5.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            error: function() {
                alert("XML file not found");
            },
            success:function(xml) {   
                     alert("Success");
             };
          });
```

Now here above the url has only sample5.xml, I want to load one more xml file say sample6.xml, can I do that? If yes then how?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just make a second ajax call. Each call can only point to a single URL. Put the second call in the `success` callback of the first one if it's important to do them in order.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Doing that, I assume, I would not be able to use the variables defined in success? Is there a way in which, I can parse the 2nd xml itself inside the success?

Comment: If you put your second ajax call in the callback of the first one, it should work fine.

Comment: @Blazemonger: And where to specify the file name then? I am sorry I am new to this, can you please show me a small code on making the callback function? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way was to store the xml values in an object and then using the .parseXML() function in jquery. By this way I can parse N number of xml objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fetch two files with one request.

You make a second Ajax call to fetch that document.

A way to do it is to use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$.when($.ajax("/file1.xml"), $.ajax("/file2.xml")).done(function(xhr1,  xhr2){
   console.log(xhr1); 
   console.log(xhr2); 
});
```